# I'm getting 'CKR_WRAPPED_KEY_INVALID' error while unwrapping. How to unwrap an AES key as DES2 key?

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, pkcs#11, des

First I wrapped an AES key using another AES key through AES/CBC algorithm. Then I tried to unwrap that AES key as DES2 key using AES/CBC algorithm by passing the key type as DES2. But while unwrapping, I got 
`CKR_WRAPPED_KEY_INVALID` error.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create 2 AES keys. lets call first key as 'key to be wrapped' and second key as 'wrapping key';
2. Wrap the first key using second key and AES/CBC algorithm through any API or something;
3. Then you will get the wrapped key as output;
4. Now Unwrap the wrapped key(i.e output) using second key(wrapping key) and AES/CBC algorithm;
5. While unwrapping, you need to give the key type as input;
6. Give the key type as DES2;
7. You will get `CKR_WRAPPED_KEY_INVALID` error.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Note: If I perform the same steps using TDES/ECB algorithm, I dont get any error. it is working fine.

Comment: Does what you attempt start to work when the value of the AES key before wrapping has odd parity, like 61F11A07D6026D4C 4F6DC4CD018CD94A ? If so, that confirms Maarten - reinstate Monica's [analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59716420/903600).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the DES parity that is the culprit. Either set the parity manually or use the first 16 bytes of a 3DES key created using `KeyGenerator` as input for the AES key.

The parity of DES is determined by the least significant bit of each byte. Each byte should have an odd number of bits set (to 1) after parity is applied.